# Is it possible to write cloudtrail logs to an s3 bucket in another, third-party AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudtrail

Is it possible to write cloudtrail logs to an s3 bucket in another, third-party AWS account?

Want to configure CloudTrail to write the logs to an S3 bucket owned by another AWS account.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can have CloudTrail deliver log files from multiple AWS accounts into a single Amazon S3 bucket. For example, you have four AWS accounts with account IDs `111111111111`, `222222222222`, and `333333333333`, and you want to configure CloudTrail to deliver log files from all four of these accounts to a bucket belonging to account `111111111111`. To accomplish this, complete the following steps in order:

1. Turn on CloudTrail in the account where the destination bucket will belong (`111111111111` in this example). Do not turn on CloudTrail in any other accounts yet. For instructions, see [Creating a trail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-create-a-trail-using-the-console-first-time.html).
2. Update the bucket policy on your destination bucket to grant cross-account permissions to CloudTrail. For instructions, see [Setting bucket policy for multiple accounts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-set-bucket-policy-for-multiple-accounts.html).
3. Turn on CloudTrail in the other accounts you want (`222222222222`, `33333333333` in this example). Configure CloudTrail in these accounts to use the same bucket belonging to the account that you specified in step 1 (`111111111111` in this example). For instructions, see [Turning on CloudTrail in additional accounts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/turn-on-cloudtrail-in-additional-accounts.html).